# Place the function that will scan the folder when asp.net application starts

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Asp.net MVC EF with Identity component.

I need to retrieve all files from a directory and add them to the database when the application starts. Eg I can not put it in the HomeController because then it will be every time someone visits the page.

This is the code I want to run.

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Images"));
            var folders = di.GetDirectories().ToList().Select(d => d.Name);

  var files = di.GetFiles();
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                var image = new Image{ name = file.ToString() };
                db.Images.Add(image);
}
```

I have tried to put it here

```
    public class ApplicationDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>
            {
    //Here
                protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
                {
    //Here
    }
}
```

But get error that I cant user `Server.MapPath`

Where should I put my code?

Comment: Bcause at this point the web appliccation is not started. 
Another solution is to do what you need in Application_Start event handler in your global.asax.cs file.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this code to the Application_Start() method in the Global.ascx.cs file, using this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath.aspx instead of Server.MapPath.

It does exactly what it says on the tin :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Put it in the Global.asax.cs file

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            ScanFiles();
        }

        private void ScanFiles()
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Images"));
            var folders = di.GetDirectories().ToList().Select(d => d.Name);

            var files = di.GetFiles();
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                var image = new Image { name = file.ToString() };
                db.Images.Add(image);

                //Hopefully, you have called SaveChanges() , because it is not seen here but hopefully you have called it in the Add method
            }
        }
```